Why does the output of this multithreaded program vary unless Thread.Join is used or Thread.Sleep is removed?
I have the following program, where I spawn 1000 threads to increment a shared variable a and then make each thread sleep for 1 second:
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{

    static volatile int a = 0;
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                a++;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            });
            t.Start();
            threads.Add(t);
        }
        // foreach(Thread t in threads) t.Join();
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

Problem:
When I run this code with the Thread.Sleep(1000) line included and t.Join() commented out, the output of Console.WriteLine(a) is less than 1000, even though I allow 60 seconds for the threads to finish.
If I uncomment the t.Join() loop or comment out the Thread.Sleep(1000) line, the output is consistently 1000.
Questions:
Why does the output vary when Thread.Sleep(1000) is present and t.Join() is commented out?
Why does the output become consistent (always 1000) when t.Join() is used or Thread.Sleep(1000) is removed?
I’d appreciate an explanation of what’s happening here in terms of thread behavior and synchronization. Thank you!

A side note: a++; is not an atomic operation, and volatile is not enough for synchronization.

One thing no one points out is that join can establish a happens before relationship between the threads end and the final print, it is an acquire operation, and without the acquire operation this would be invalid C or C++ (the computer doesn't necessarily need to read it from the main memory, it can read it from the caches) .... not sure about C# memory model but since the runtime will rely on native code for threads synchronization, it will be invoking C or C++ code

TBH was not able to reproduce the foreach(Thread t in threads) t.Join(); vs Thread.Sleep effect - both consistently (on relatively small number of attempts though) give the "expected" sum (maybe there is some setup difference that leads to not all threads being able to complete though with Thread.Sleep(60000) it is very doubtful). I would suggest to change the code to:
var t = new Thread(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);   
    a++;
});

i.e. change the order of operations then the foreach(Thread t in threads) t.Join(); trick will stop working (at least "on my machine"). The fact that it was is a mere coincidence, I would guess related to the fact that a++ is relatively fast operation and since you are starting thread before adding it to the list and creating the next one it has enough time to complete.
Changing sleep and increment order brings (at least for me) the main issue to the front - increment (a++) is not atomic, and using it in multithreaded context makes you program invalid you should use some synchronization or atomic version of the operation (if exists).
For example Interlocked.Increment will make your program correct:
var t = new Thread(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);   
    Interlocked.Increment(ref a);
});

I would also recommend to check out:

Threading in C# by Joseph Albahari - a bit dated by concepts are still relevant
The Deadlock Empire - the game exposing some atomicity and synchronization pitfalls (via .NET)


my problem is sleep(1000) is after a++. This show the threads do not start even after one minute except you call join.  I tested it with latest VS 2022. I suggest to make more threads to see if you can reproduce....

@MinimusHeximus interesting. How long does it take for the Join version to run?

a few seconds...

@MinimusHeximus " This show the threads do not start even after one minute except you call join" - this statement is a bit doubtful TBH. Have you checked the number of threads created?

a: 992    threads.Count: 1000

@MinimusHeximus please add Console.WriteLine(threads.Count(t => t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)); after the Console.WriteLine(a) and check the output.

threads.Count(t => t.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) is 1000... so the issue is with atomic operations...


Why does the output vary when Thread.Sleep(1000) is present and t.Join() is commented out?

The OS may schedule threads whenever it wish. So chances are not all threads have had the chance to run. Since the OS do not provide any specific timing guarantees you cannot rely on just waiting to ensure that threads has run.

Why does the output become consistent (always 1000) when t.Join()

Join blocks execution of the current thread until the joining thread has completed. So if you join all the threads you can be sure that all threads has completed execution.
But that does not mean that a is guaranteed to be 1000. It is possible for the first thread to:

Read a as 0
Become preempted by the operating system
Resume execution after all other threads has completed
Increment a to 1
Write out 1 to memory

Resulting in an output of 1. volatile does not prevent this, you would need a lock, or Interlocked.Increment to increment a variable safely.
Multi threading is difficult, and you cannot use tests like this to verify that that a behavior is correct. A test might succeed a million times, but fail on another computer, or when there is a high load, or when there is a full moon. At best you can verify that a behavior is incorrect. You need to know the hazards and how to solve them. Managed threading best practices is a good start, but there are plenty of other good articles on thread safety.
